# HTML5 Canvas element not stable on android mobile applications

Tags: android, html, canvas, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I have created a simple rotating logos animation in HTML5 using Canvas and KineticJS.

Packaged it into an app for Android using PhoneGap Build Services.

On some Mobiles it works seamlessly while on other mostly above Android ver 4.0 the Canvas elements and its layers either duplicates or is not visible.

Is there a issue with KineticJS framework for mobile applications, or Canvas not that supported yet...

Comment: paste some of the code or print screen , so we can get some idea

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=canvas

Comment: Here is the link [link]http://www.darshanrane.com/rnd/canvas/canvaserror.jpg  
@FelixLahmer Have checked that link, it shows support.

Comment: This is android canvas bugs. Not KineticJS. Try to use this tips: http://slash-system.com/en/how-to-fix-android-html5-canvas-issues/